# YouTube video autoplay

Tags: autoplay

I wish to enable autoplay with sound and tried added code
-- `?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay"`

But it did not work, how I should do for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `allow="autoplay"` and it should be fine. Here's an example:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/[Video ID]I?&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```